# Reactive values not updating when actionButton is clicked with shinyjs

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-reactivity, shinyjs, shinywidgets

I have a Shiny app in which a `pickerInput()` is updated based on the value selected in another `pickerInput()`.

```r
library("shiny")
library("shinyWidgets")

ui <- fluidPage(
  shinyjs::useShinyjs(),
  tags$h2("Update pickerInput"),
  
  fluidRow(
    column(
      width = 5, offset = 1,
      pickerInput(
        inputId = "pl",
        label = "Lower",
        choices = letters
      )
    ),
    column(
      width = 5,
      pickerInput(
        inputId = "pu",
        label = "Upper",
        choices = LETTERS
      )
    )
  ),
  
  fluidRow(
    column(
      width = 10, offset = 1,
      actionButton("b1", label = "Update 1"),
      actionButton("b2", label = "Update 2"),
      textOutput("pu_printed"),
    )
  )
  
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  observeEvent(input$b1, {
    updatePickerInput(
      session = session, inputId = "pu",
      selected = LETTERS[letters == input$pl]
    )
    shinyjs::click("b2")
  })
  
  pur <- eventReactive(input$b2, {
    print(input$pu)
    input$pu
  })
  
  output$pu_printed <- renderText({
    paste("Selected Upper: ", pur())
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server, options = list(launch.browser = TRUE))
```

[image]

I expect that upon selecting a value with the "Lower" input and clicking the "Update 1" button, the following should happen:

1. "Upper" input will automatically update based on the value in the "Lower" input
2. The (new) value in the "Upper" input (from step 1) will print to the console
3. The (new) value in the "Upper" input (from step 1) will be rendered as text under the buttons.

However, only expectation 1 actually occurs (the "Upper" input is updated). However, the console printout and text render remain set to the previous value ("A" in the case below).

[image]

Changing the "Lower" input and clicking "Update 1" again shows that the rendered text has updated to the first selection from "Lower" (in this case, "M"). Essentially, the rendered text is always one selection behind.

[image]

The same thing happens when the UI is generated dynamically. I have not reproduced the screenshots because the results are the same, but here is the code.

```r
library("shiny")
library("shinyWidgets")

ui <- fluidPage(
  shinyjs::useShinyjs(),
  tags$h2("Update pickerInput"),
  
  uiOutput("o1")
  
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  output$o1 <- renderUI({
    tagList(fluidRow(
      column(
        width = 5, offset = 1,
        pickerInput(
          inputId = "pl",
          label = "Lower",
          choices = letters
        )
      ),
      column(
        width = 5,
        pickerInput(
          inputId = "pu",
          label = "Upper",
          choices = LETTERS
        )
      )
    ),
    fluidRow(
      column(
        width = 10, offset = 1,
        actionButton("b1", label = "Update 1"),
        actionButton("b2", label = "Update 2"),
        textOutput("pu_printed"),
      )
    ))
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$b1, {
    updatePickerInput(
      session = session, inputId = "pu",
      selected = LETTERS[letters == input$pl]
    )
    shinyjs::click("b2")
  })
  
  pur <- eventReactive(input$b2, {
    print(input$pu)
    input$pu
  })
  
  output$pu_printed <- renderText({
    paste("Selected Upper: ", pur())
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server, options = list(launch.browser = TRUE))
```

I know that the `shinyjs::click("b2")` is firing correctly because the `print()` statement is output to the console, however the value `input$pu` appears to always be one selection behind. What do I need to change so that the updated value of `input$pu` is available when `shinyjs::click("b2")` fires?

Comment: This is familiar problem. In my experience, the best way to do something like this is with dynamic inputs in your server script and `renderUI`.   Those updateInput functions can be difficult to fit in to the reactive chain of events, as you are experiencing.

Comment: In your case, 2 and 3 are working as expected.  If you want it to show immediate reactivity, please change `pur <- eventReactive(..)`  to `pur <- reactive(...)`

Comment: @SmokeyShakers using dynamic input has the same issue (I have added example code to the post).

Comment: I mean making ONLY your picker input that is named pu,  dynamic and getting rid of the updatePickerInput entirely.  Ideally you want the button firing to filter a reactive vector of choices.  Then, when that vector is filtered,  the input will re-render with the new choices.